# Selecting rows between dateTime with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like select rows between an initialDate and finalDate which one are coming from a form submited and I've done it like this on localhost (it works fine):

```
public function getReport($initialDate, $finalDate)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->where('s.date BETWEEN :initialDate AND :finalDate')
                ->setParameter('initialDate', $initialDate->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->setParameter('finalDate', $finalDate->format('Y-m-d'));
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

but when I host my website, it return 0 result I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Any difference in PHP/Symfony core versions between your local host and webhost?

Comment: no I've the same extension with php and for the Symfony2 I dont change anything

Comment: Display your SQL `echo $qb->getQuery()->getSQL()` and test your query manually on your server. We can't help you in this situation since we don't know if data are the same in your prod / dev database, and if the server configuration is the same.

Comment: I assume you loaded the database from locahost to wherever you are now running this?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the DateTime object instead of formatting it as a string.

Try with:

```
public function getReport($initialDate, $finalDate)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->where('s.date BETWEEN :initialDate AND :finalDate')
                ->setParameter('initialDate', $initialDate)
                ->setParameter('finalDate', $finalDate);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

public function getReport($initialDate, $finalDate)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');

                ->where('s.date BETWEEN :initialDate AND :finalDate')
                ->setParameter('initialDate', $initialDate)
                ->setParameter('finalDate', $finalDate);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

You can do a BETWEEN statement with the EXPR component as follow:

```
public function getReport($initialDate, $finalDate)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->between('s.date',':initialDate',':finalDate'))
        ->setParameter('initialDate', $initialDate)
        ->setParameter('finalDate', $finalDate);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: all the code you give me is working in localhost perfectly but when I put it on the remote server it still return null I don't understand at all

Comment: When I set the variables like this: $initialDate = new \DateTime('2012-12-03'); in the repository I get the right value

Comment: how is defined the filed type on doctrine? datetime or date?

Comment: all the field are defined as dateTime. I'm just realize something: the initial date varibale is null when the form is submitted and also there diference between the way sonata_type_datetime_picker' display the content of the form in localhost than on the server exp: sep 1... on localhost and september 1st ... on the remote server therefore I think the problem would be the sonata formType sonata_type_datetime_picker'